# Can I add number of days to the (dayoftheweek) to get another day?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a date and from that I find the dayoftheweek . Lets say the day I found is Tuesday . I have a variable that has duration . Lets say the duration is 5 days . Will I be able to add 5 to Tuesday and get Saturday as the answer . Tuesday should be considered as day 1 and saturday as day 5.

```
date = 04/13/2021                         #in mm/dd/yyyy
dayoftheweek = GetDayOfWeek(date)         #Tuesday
duration = 5
```

Is this correct?

```
finaldayoftheweek = dayoftheweek + 5        # I want to get Saturday as answer
```

If not how do I do that ?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely separate languages.

Comment: I don't get it! Is this a java, javascript, or a python question?!!! Please make up your mind

Comment: I don't want to do this in any specific language . Please tell me if there is a way to do this in any of these languages. Thats what I meant . I know java and javascript are different languages @Scott Marcus

Comment: Add and then mod 7 works in many languages, but it depends how the days of the week are numbered.

Comment: @HassenCh. Is there a way to do this in any of these languages

Comment: @Lucky1234 - You should pick one for the purpose of this question, and have your code match.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Please tell me how to do this in python

Comment: You shouldn't ask how to implement something, but you should explain what is your need, explain what you did, and then have suggestions for example. Why not simple add 5 days to the original date and then get the day of the week? That would be very simple

Comment: Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks.

Comment: @HassenCh. I think I have made it very clear . I do not know why you are not getting the question . I didn't want to copy the code and that is why I asked it in plain english. I want to know if we can add numberofdays to a dayofweek to get another dayofweek

Comment: @Lucky1234 sadly I think that it's not. Just read all the comments to see people saying that the question is not well asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Saturday, add 4 days.

```js
/*
 * Obtain the day of the week, tht will occur a number of days after the
 * provided {@code dateString}.<p>
 * @param  {String} dateString - format: mm/dd/yyyy
 * @param  {Numer}  addDays    - days to add to date
 * @return {String} returns the day of week in its 'long' format.
 */
const getDayOfWeek = (dateString, addDays) => {
  const [month, date, year] = dateString.split('/').map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
  const d = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + addDays);
  return d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
}

console.log(getDayOfWeek('04/13/2021', 4)); // Saturday
```

If all you want to do is add a number of days to a day of week and get another day of week then use a modulo operation.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = 7

start_day_of_week = 2 # Tuesday
number_of_days_to_add = 10 # or 3, 17, 24, 31, etc...
end_day_of_week = (start_day_of_week + number_of_days_to_add) % DAYS_IN_A_WEEK

print(end_day_of_week) # 5 (Saturday)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the need of the question. I guess that he wants a day in input 'Tuesday', a days diff, then a day in output, 'Saturday'

Comment: @HassenCh. _"I want to get Saturday as answer"_

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in Python, however since you want Saturday, you should add 4:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2021, 4, 13)                         
dayoftheweek = date.strftime("%A")         #Tuesday
duration = 4                         #Since you mentioned you wanted Saturday

finaldate = date + datetime.timedelta(days= duration)

finaldayoftheweek = finaldayoftheweek.strftime("%A")    #Saturday
```